# how to configure shiro roles for web project

Tags: jsp, config, shiro

I have this config currently

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.usernameParam = user
authc.passwordParam = pass
authc.rememberMeParam = remember
authc.successUrl = /index.jsp

[urls]
/** = authc
/index.jsp = roles[user]
/cards.jsp = roles[user]
/jobs.jsp = roles[admin]

[users]
lol = ba, user
admin = ba, admin
```

And the login works, but when I login with `lol` username i can still access the /jobs.jsp page, so how to prevent user from accessing the /jobs.jsp page?

Also why when i remove `/** = authc` the login dos not work, it just does post request to the login page without processing the login?

Where can I find the definitive guide on how to configure roles for web based project using shiro?

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find the definitive guide on how to configure roles for
>   web based project using shiro?

BalusC has a great post on it, I've used it when I integrated Shiro to my app 
http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html

And regarding your main question, your cfg seems wrong (the **password** is missing before the role specifications) , please see

http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-%5Cusers%5C

Line Format

Each line in the [users] section must conform to the following format:

username = password, roleName1, roleName2, ..., roleNameN

The value on the left of the equals sign is the username
The first value on the right of the equals sign is the user's password. A password is required.
Any comma-delimited values after the password are the names of roles assigned to that user. Role names are optional.

Comment: what about my main question ? :D can you spot something wrong with the config

Comment: if the config is wrong i would not be able to deploy the app, but im not missing the password, check again in roles section

Comment: ok, i found a partial solution but using the shiro tags <shiro:hasRole name="admin"> and i limit the links a user can see but still the url request is doable